# Estimation of ground state energy from wave function

Tags: quantum-chemistry

> Given the wave functions of a particle in a 1D box below determine (for each pair) if the left or right function gives a better estimation of the ground state energy if the variational method is used. No calculaltions are needed.
>
> [image]

I am having some problem understand how to solve this question. We are not allowed to use any graphing calculators and the *tip* says "try to plot some points and compare it with the exact wave function", which I don't find helpful.

All help is truly appreciated!

Comment: Probably you are supposed to calculate the numerical value of all those wave functions for a couple of x values, like x = 0.2, then x = 0.5, then x = 0.8. This being done, you should intercompare these results (f(0.5):f(0,2 for example) and then compare with the ground state solution (sinusoid). The numerical values relative to one another maybe similar to what is obtained with the sinus function.

Answer (score 2):

The [variational method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_method_(quantum_mechanics)) uses a linear combination of functions as an estimate of the true wavefunction. It works by adjusting coefficients in the linear combination to minimize the energy of the trial wavefunction. This is the best estimate of the true wavefunction using the restricted basis set. The variational principle states that adding more (new) basis functions to the linear combination always improves the estimate.

In your problem (or according to your instructions), you don't really optimize anything (except for the last comparison), because the normalization condition fixes the value of the $c_i$ coefficients, but you can estimate which of the two functions appears most like the true wavefunction, as this should return a minimum energy.

The [ground state solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box) has the form $$\psi \propto sin(\pi x)$$
when x is in units of the box length, with bounds at $x=0$ and $x=1$ (and null wavefunction outside these bounds). This function has nodes at $x=0$ and $x=1$ and is concave with a single maximum at $x=\frac12$. By evaluating the functions at the bounds, in the midpoint and at one or more other points you should get an idea about the shape of each function and thereby which are better. It would of course be easier to plot them. Consider to the extent possible symmetry and whether bounds are satisfied (which they must for the solution to be at all physically reasonable - remember that the energy blows up if the wavefunction samples points out of bounds.

The last comparison is a "trick question". There you have to take into account the variational principle which is mentioned in the first paragraph of this answer.

Comment: What insight allows you to determine whether $\psi_3$ or $\psi_4$ is better? The other seem obvious.

Comment: @user5713492 the true wavefunction has even symmetry

Comment: Yeah, but...
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+x%5E2%281-x%5E2%29+d%5E2%2Fdx%5E2%28x%5E2%281-x%5E2%29%29dx
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+%28x%5E2%281-x%5E2%29%29%5E2dx
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+x%5E2%281-x%29%5E2+d%5E2%2Fdx%5E2%28x%5E2%281-x%29%5E2%29dx
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+%28x%5E2%281-x%29%5E2%29%5E2dx ... OK, I guess you're right but I think you can compose examples where a wave function with wrong symmetry is better.

Comment: @user5713492 Sorry but I cannot decrypt your comment. In words, what's your point?

Comment: Just using Wolfram Alpha to do the integrals quickly.

Comment: @user5713492 Ok, you evaluated expectation values for the wavefunctions (energies). I'm pretty sure $\psi_4$ is the better function based on symmetry, and if I evaluated your Wolfram results correctly ($E = <\psi^* H \psi>= -N\int \psi^* (\partial \psi/ \partial x^2) dx$) then that is indeed the correct answer. Thanks for the nice Wolfram example btw.

Comment: I agree though that symmetry alone does not seem a sufficient condition, but in this case it is a good guide.

Comment: Where asymmetric trial function wins:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+%28%28x%2B1%29x%281-x%29%282-x%29%2B%281%2F2%29x%281%2F2-x%29%281-x%29%29d%5E2%2Fdx%5E2%28%28x%2B1%29x%281-x%29%282-x%29%2B%281%2F2%29x%281%2F2-x%29%281-x%29%29+dx
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+%28%28x%2B1%29x%281-x%29%282-x%29%2B%281%2F2%29x%281%2F2-x%29%281-x%29%29%5E2+dx
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+%28x%281-x%29%29d%5E2%2Fdx%5E2%28x%281-x%29%29+dx 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+%28x%281-x%29%29%5E2+dx

Comment: @user5713492 nice example :-) Of course, knowing the true wavefunction is symmetric would usually point the search toward symmetric solutions, but your point is made.

Comment: @BuckThorn: I like your answer very much, and appreciate you putting so much time into writing it with care. I find it unusual that it was closed as "off-topic" because I think it's perfectly on topic, so it's a pity that your answer cannot be chosen as "accepted". Would you mind helping support our proposal to start a stack exchange just for materials modeling and quantum chemistry? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=NDY4N2I5MzBmODViNGQwYWM2MTBmMzVkMzc0OWU0ZjQ5NDU2YTVhYzQyMmEyY2IwYjdjYzlmZDMwMWQyZmJhNGBP4m1cf3-vYfnwUjsCFf90E8N7syRuU35ETDRpKo-U0

Comment: Hi Buck Thorn! It seems that your Area51 account isn't linked properly to your Stack Exchange Network account, which might cause you not to get an invitation to participate in the private beta stage, can you try to see if this answer:
https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29706/please-make-sure-you-link-your-other-stack-exchange-accounts helps to fix the problem? On the commitment list you should show up as having 10k reputation but it's listing you as only 51 (which is the default for people that have confirmed their email address).

Comment: This says something about signing into Area51 first and then committing, rather than the other way around: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29985/190792.

Comment: That's probably why it doesn't know which Stack Exchange account to link! Perhaps we can wait until you have the normal browser available again, and you can try with your usual email address. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it with your original email address now?

Comment: @BuckThorn: People have found it to work in Chrome's in-cognito mode. I also find it very frustrating that SE hasn't fixed this, because we have ~900 members in the Materials Modeling Stack Exchange facebook group, but because it's so hard to sign in properly, we have only 76 that are actually signed into Area51.... so this makes it extremely hard for us to reach the minimum requirements to get launched! If we don't meet the minimum requirements within about 2 more months, they'll permanently delete our proposal.

Comment: Hi @BuckThorn, have you had any luck? A user this morning was having problems but it got fixed (his Area51 account was completely deleted and re-created from scratch, and this time it connected properly to the rest of the SE network).

Comment: Hi @BuckThorn, in this answer: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29933/persistent-bugs-hindering-many-of-our-users-from-participating/29985#29985 a user got it to work by clicking "log out" on Area51, then she was told that her Area51 account would be permanently deleted. Then she gave instructions and screenshots for what she did next, which worked. Some people got it to work when they used Chrome's in-cognito mode, or when they deleted their browser's cookies. Is it helpful? Please try!

Comment: It looks like it's working now !!!

Comment: I think the only step missing now is to click the confirm link in the email they sent you.